# Type of anonymous type

Tags: java, oop, class

This is an interesting little thing I've encountered. I was messing around with anonymous types and I wrote something like:

```
public class Test {
    public static void method(Object obj) {
        System.out.println(obj.getClass().getName());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        method(new Object() {
           int n = 0; 
        });
    }
}
```

Well, I was quite surprised when the result printed was in fact `test.Test$1` which is the name of the class in which the anonymous object was defined (it's still the same if you move the method that prints the type name to another class).

Can someone explain this behavior? Is this specified in the Java standard or is yet another "undefined behavior"?

Comment: Which behaviour exactly are you concerned about?

Comment: That is actually a well-known behaviour. Anonymous class get names too because compiler needs to know about those types somehow...

Comment: **No** `undefined behavior` in java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look again, you'll see that the class name printed out has a trailing `$1`.  Inner classes always get named by concatenating `$` and the inner class name to the containing class' name.  Anonymous classes simply get a number instead of a name.  So effectively, the class name that's getting printed out is saying "the first anonymous class contained in test.Test".

Answer (score 4):

test.Test$1 is not the same as test.Test. For instance, if you declare an inner type:

```
public class Test {
    // ...
    private class Foo {};
}
```

then the qualified name of Foo will be test.Test$Foo. $1 means "the first anonymous type declared in test.Test".

Answer (score 3):

it is printing the name of the anonymous class which is created with `new Object() { ... }`, its working as expected. Basically, you have extended Object to create a new class (and its instance) while not naming it, so the jvm names it automatically as the enclosing class followed by $ and an index

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's accepted behaviour.  Nested classes is always denoted as package.outer class$nested class. For example test.Test$NestedTest, for the nested class "NestedTest" inside the class "Test" in the package "test".

Anonymous classes are merely numbered in order of definition (since they have no name).  For example,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    method(new Object() {
        int n = 0;
    });

    Object m = new Test() {
        int n = 0;
    };

    method(new Object() {
        int m = 0;
    });

    method(m);
    method(m);
    method(m);
}
```

will display

```
Test$1
Test$3
Test$2
Test$2
Test$2
```

Nice question!

Answer (score 2):

When you use the syntax `new SomeClass() { ... }`, you create an *anonymous* class. Java names anonymous classes as `<containing class>$number`, where `number` is the one-based cardinal number of the appearance of the anonymous class in the containing class.